# Using glob to import txt files to an array for interpolation

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, glob

Currently I am using data (wavelength, flux) in txt format and have six txt files. The wavelengths are the same but the fluxes are different. I have imported the txt files using `pd.read_cvs` (as can be seen in the code) and assigned each flux a different name. These different named fluxes are placed in an array. Finally, I interpolate the fluxes with a temperature array. The codes works and because currently I only have six files writing the code this way is ok. The problem I have moving forward is that when I have 100s of txt files I need a better method.

How can I use glob to import the txt files, assign a different name to each flux (if that is necessary) and finally interpolate? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

fcf = 0.0000001 # flux conversion factor
wcf = 10 #wave conversion factor
temperature = np.array([725,750,775,800,825,850])

# import files and assign column headers; blank to ignore spaces

c1p = pd.read_csv("../c/725.txt",sep=" ",header=None)
c1p.columns = ["blank","0","blank","blank","1"]
c2p = pd.read_csv("../c/750.txt",sep=" ",header=None)
c2p.columns = ["blank","0","blank","blank","1"]
c3p = pd.read_csv("../c/775.txt",sep=" ",header=None)
c3p.columns = ["blank","0","blank","blank","1"]
c4p = pd.read_csv("../c/800.txt",sep=" ",header=None)
c4p.columns = ["blank","0","blank","blank","1"]
c5p = pd.read_csv("../c/825.txt",sep=" ",header=None)
c5p.columns = ["blank","0","blank","blank","1"]
c6p = pd.read_csv("../c/850.txt",sep=" ",header=None)
c6p.columns = ["blank","0","blank","blank","1"]

wave = np.array(c1p['0']/wcf)

c1fp = np.array(c1p['1']*fcf)
c2fp = np.array(c2p['1']*fcf)
c3fp = np.array(c3p['1']*fcf)
c4fp = np.array(c4p['1']*fcf)
c5fp = np.array(c5p['1']*fcf)
c6fp = np.array(c6p['1']*fcf)

cfp = np.array([c1fp,c2fp,c3fp,c4fp,c5fp,c6fp])

flux_int = interpolate.interp1d(temperature,cfp,axis=0,kind='linear',bounds_error=False,fill_value='extrapolate')
```

My attempts so far...I think I have loaded the files into a list using glob as

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import glob

c_list=[]

path = "../c/*.*"

for file in glob.glob(path): 
    print(file)
    c = pd.read_csv(file,sep=" ",header=None)
    c.columns = ["blank","0","blank","blank","1"]
    c_list.append
```

I am still unsure how to extract just the fluxes into an array in order to interpolate. I will continue to post my attempts.

My updated code

```
fcf = 0.0000001
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import glob

c_list=[]

path = "../c/*.*"

for file in glob.glob(path):
    print(file)
    c = pd.read_csv(file,sep=" ",header=None)
    c.columns = ["blank","0","blank","blank","1"]
    c = c['1']*fcf
    c_list.append(c)
    
fluxes = np.array(c_list)

temperature = np.array([7250,7500,7750,8000,8250,8500])
flux_int =interpolate.interp1d(temperature,fluxes,axis=0,kind='linear',bounds_error=False,fill_value='extrapolate')
```

When I run this code I get the following error

```
raise ValueError("x and y arrays must be equal in length along "

ValueError: x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis.
```

I think the error in the code that needs correcting is here `fluxes = np.array(c_list)`. This is one list of all fluxes but I need a list of fluxes from each file. How is this done?

Final attempt

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import glob

c_list=[]
path = "../c/*.*"
for file in glob.glob(path):
    print(file)
    c = pd.read_csv(file,sep=" ",header=None)
    c.columns = ["blank","0","blank","blank","1"]
    c = c['1']* 0.0000001
    c_list.append(c)
    

c1=np.array(c_list[0])
c2=np.array(c_list[1])
c3=np.array(c_list[2])
c4=np.array(c_list[3])
c5=np.array(c_list[4])
c6=np.array(c_list[5])

fluxes = np.array([c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6])
temperature = np.array([7250,7500,7750,8000,8250,8500])
flux_int = interpolate.interp1d(temperature,fluxes,axis=0,kind='linear',bounds_error=False,fill_value='extrapolate')
```

This code work but I am still not sure about

```
c1=np.array(c_list[0])
c2=np.array(c_list[1])
c3=np.array(c_list[2])
c4=np.array(c_list[3])
c5=np.array(c_list[4])
c6=np.array(c_list[5])
```

Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's 2 things that you can tdo:

1. Instead of
   `c = c['1']* 0.0000001`

   try doing `c = c['1'].to_numpy()* 0.0000001`

   This will build a list of numpy Arrays rather than a list of pandas Series
2. When constructing fluxes, you can just do
   `fluxes = np.array(c_list)`